# Why am I serving up SimplyClassicRemodeling.com instead of redirecting to CJSHayward.com?

Tags: apache-2.4, 301-redirect

I have a client website where the client requested that a website be removed as it details where his business was years back, not where it's moving now. I tried to broach the concept of an update, but he wants it removed.

The domain is SimplyClassicRemodeling.com, and I'm trying to find out how it is managing to resist changes. I set the Apache VirtualHost to redirect all traffic to my main site, and then edited the source files to have a meta refresh on each complete page, which I cannot see. The impression I get on that end is that my server is not the one that's being consulted for SimplyClassicRemodeling.com traffic. I write a modified webpage with a meta refresh, view the source and hard reload, and there is no meta tag redirecting to CJSHayward.com.

The nameservers for SimplyClassicRemodeling.com are ns1.mydomain.com, ns2.mydomain.com, ns3.mydomain.com, and ns4.mydomain.com, which is what I think I want (I am working through mydomain.com). The A records for SimplyClassicRemodeling.com and *.SimplyClassicRemodeling.com (there is no separate entry for www.SimplyClassicRemodeling.com) both point to 69.163.221.78, the same address as CJSHayward.com. So in the previous paragraph I describe behavior suggesting that SimplyClassicRemodeling.com is being served up from somewhere entirely different from my VPS, but when I try to get an IP, I get my VPS's IP, no more / no less.

I've tried adding meta refresh tags on the backup server, and it doesn't seem to cause any changes. I have not yet loaded SimplyClassicRemodeling.com and been redirected by any means.

The /etc/apache2/sites-enabled entry is below; "grep -i simply *" only returns this instance:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin CJSHayward@POBox.com

    ServerName simplyclassicremodeling.com
    DocumentRoot /home/cjsh/doug
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    #<Directory /home/cjsh/>
        #Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        #AllowOverride None
        #Order allow,deny
        #allow from all
    #</Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.shtml index.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /servererror.html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* https://cjshayward.com [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin CJSHayward@POBox.com
    ServerName www.simplyclassicremodeling.com
    DocumentRoot /home/cjsh/oldmirror

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cjshayward.com$1 [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

How am I managing to update Apache and add meta refreshes and still have the unbudged old version of the site freshly served up?

Comment: Where is this site being hosted?

Comment: That's part of the problem. My intent is to host on my VPS at 69.163.221.78 , and MyDomain's A record and a command-line ``host simplyclassicremodeling.com`` both point to my host. However, I've had multiple failures at having any change on my host alter the website behavior in any way. Short answer, I don't know even though I tried to nail that down before asking my question.

Comment: Not from out here on the Internet! `host simplyclassicremodeling.com` returns a CNAME to `haywardfamily.org.`, which itself has an A record of `24.15.85.69`. Definitely not the VPS you intended. And you also have a naked domain with a CNAME, which (1) they should not have allowed you to attempt, and (2) will cause a wide variety of problems until it is fixed.

Comment: Please restate your response as an answer so I can accept it.